# How to mapping Char(20) data type as Primary Key MySQL in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

i want to ask about mapping Char(20) data type as Primary Key MySQL in C#?

I have some code in Models like :

```
public string StudentID { get; set; }
```

I have some code in DatabaseContext like :

```
builder
.Entity<Student>()
  .ToTable("Student")
    .HasKey(m => new
    {
      m.StudentID
    });
```

The data is like : ST-01-01-2017-001

Why in Swagger Response Body is no content and in Response Code is 500?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but how do you expect us to even remotely help you, when you leave out the most important piece of information: The error message itself?! Please read the help center articles on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
.HasKey(m => new
{
  m.StudentID
});
```

to

```
.HasKey(m => m.StudentID);
```

Comment: still in Swagger Response Body is no content and in Response Code is 500